# MYSQL - Find 30 rows from 3 tables where the phone number matches

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (source1, source2, source3) that have a phone number column named phone.  There are no duplicate within a given table (i.e. source1 contains no duplicate phone numbers within it's table, same with source2 & source3).

If the phone column is the same for source1, source2 & source3 then I want to display the row from all 3 tables.  So, if this matched for (555) 555-5555, then this would result in 3 rows being displayed (the complete rows with all columns).  I simply need to limit this to 30 phone numbers.

Can anyone help with this query?

Answer (score 2):

you can use union all

```
select  phone from (
   ( select phone
   from source1
   order by  phone limit 30 )
   union all 
   ( select phone
   from source2
    order by phone limit 30)
   union all
   ( select phone
   from source3
   order by phone limit 30 )
) t
```

and limit the result to 30

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  Two things.  The phone number shows up blank in the result.  Also, it displays only 30 rows (of blank phone column only), I need 30 rows of all columns from all 3 tables for a total of 90 rows.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior   answer  updated  .. hope is what you are looking for

Comment: I get the following error with your code:  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'phone limit 30)
   union all
   ( select phone
   from source1
   ' at line 4`

Comment: I just updated my question with the query that almost gives me what I'm looking for, I just need to print each row from each table on a seperate line instead of merging them onto one line.  Can you help with that?  `SELECT source1.*, source2.*, source3.* FROM source1, source2, source3 WHERE source1.phone = source2.phone = source3.phone LIMIT 30;`

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior   this is another question ...change the question  is not fair  .. should be correct  .. post a new proper question .. instead  of modify this  .. and if my firts question is correct for originla queston mark it as accepted .. eventually comment me the link to new question

Comment: My apologies about the confusion here my friend.  I'm a newbie trying to figure out how do use this site & how to run a query.  Your query kept producing blank results, so I had to keep searching for answers & found something that I think can help others understand what I'm asking.  I thought updating the question would help you to provide a proper solution. However, I will delete my update & post a new question, since it seems like that's what I should have done.

Comment: Ok ... then you say me that the  query produce  blank result  .. you mean the query don't produce any rows .. or in the result there are some blank rows? ..

Comment: I've been banned from asking new questions apparently, so I can't ask a new question on the site anymore.  So, all I can say is:  `SELECT source1.*, source2.*, source3.* FROM source1, source2, source3 WHERE source1.phone = source2.phone = source3.phone LIMIT 30;` produces close to the result...I just need to print all rows separately instead of together.  You query was producing 1 column "phone" & all blank.

Comment: In my query I select only a column  named  phone  ... no others   because you haven't provided  the others columns name .. you can add the column s  you need  ..adding (comma separated) the related column name  .. hope this is clear ..

Answer (score 0):

using union:

```
SELECT 'phone'
 FROM (SELECT 'phone' FROM source1
    UNION
    SELECT 'phone' FROM source
    UNION
   SELECT 'phone' FROM source3
   ) AS U
WHERE U.phone='(555) 555-5555'  Limit 30
```

Comment: The phone # (555) 555-5555 was just an example of the matching that would take place.  I don't need to match a particular phone number.  I need to search the DB for the phone #.